# Find line matching an expression, copy entire line, insert in new line and replace the expression

Tags: awk, sed

I have several files (yml, tf, xml) for which I need to find a string i.e. var1, and then insert a new line with foo2, the rest of the line is unchanged.
Example

```
variable "my_vars" {
  type = "map"

  default = {
    var1 = "10.48.225.160/28"
    var2 = "10.48.225.160/28"
    var3 = "10.48.225.160/28"
    var4 = "10.48.225.160/28"
  }
}
```

I tried the code below but I need the edit in place.

```
import sys
import string

def find(substr, replstr, infile):
    f = open(infile,"rw")
    lines = f.readlines()
    for i in range(len(lines)):
        if substr in lines[i]:
            j = string.replace(lines[i], substr, replstr)
            lines.insert(i + 1, j)
    print "\n".join(lines)

old_env = sys.argv[1]
new_env = sys.argv[2]
file = sys.argv[3]

find(old_env, new_env, file)
```

Comment: And what have you tired till now ? What isnt working for you ? Can you show us the attempts you've done or are you expecting a straight up answer here ?

Comment: @JasonStanley, I have tried sed, awk and python. I need the edit in place and can't find a way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

```
import sys
import string

def find(substr, replstr, infile):
    f = open(infile,"r")
    lines = f.readlines()

    for i in range(len(lines)):
        if substr in lines[i]:
            j = string.replace(lines[i], substr, replstr)
            lines.insert(i + 1, j)
    print "".join(lines)
    f.close()

    f = open(infile,"w")
    k = "".join(lines)
    f.writelines(k)
    f.close()

old_env = sys.argv[1]
new_env = sys.argv[2]
file = sys.argv[3]

find(old_env, new_env, file)
```

The one caveat is there is a match on the last line of the file, the iterator will miss this.